# Problems with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write simple web app in VSCode. I have little misunderstanding. May be its really simple thing, but i don't know why it doesn't work normally like in examples which i saw.

i have js file (script.js)

```
 function getHistory(){
    return document.getElementById("history-value").innerText;
}
alert( getHistory());
```

and my index.html where i'm using div's tags

```
     <div class="result">
        <div class="history">
            <p  id="history-value">55555</p>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
            <p id="output-value" class="output-value">7777777</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in beginning of course referense to js

```
<head> 
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js">
        </script>
</head>
```

But allert are not working. I can't see nothing. If i use

```
console.log (document.getElementById("history-value").innerText );
```

it shows null in console window.

Please explain me what's wrong with it?

Comment: There is no `innerText` property on a DOM element. You probably want `innerHTML` or `textContent`.

Comment: @alesc ``.innerText`` should work to get the value ``55555`` that is in the DOM element.

Comment: @alesc That's just wrong.

Comment: I know. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As Java script is loaded before html page so you have to add script tage at bottom of the page in your case as you are taking value of `history-value` element which you have added after script tag so when script tag is loaded there is no element with id history-value so you will get null. So you have to add this script after this element

**index.html**

```
<head> 
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="result">
        <div class="history">
            <p  id="history-value">55555</p>
        </div>
        <div class="output">
            <p id="output-value" class="output-value">7777777</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

**script.js**

```
function getHistory(){
    return document.getElementById("history-value").innerText;
}
alert( getHistory());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was so blind

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `<script>` tag appears in the `<head>` section of your document, and when the script loads, the rest of your HTML has not yet been loaded by the browser, so the `<p id="history-value">` tag effectively does not yet exist as far as the browser is concerned.

In this case, you should put your `<script>` tag just before the `</body>` tag, or at the very least after the `<p id="history-value">` tag, so that `<p>` tag appears before the Javascript attempts to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script runs when there is no `history-value` element.
Are you sure you are running the code after document has been loaded?

Your code work in the following snippet (but I guess is due to the fact that javscript is loaded at the end of the document).

But to make sure you can place into a

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( event ) {
  // your code here
})
```

```js
function getHistory(){
  return document.getElementById("history-value").innerText;
}

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( event ) {
  alert(getHistory());
});
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <div class="history">
    <p id="history-value">55555</p>
  </div>
  <div class="output">
    <p id="output-value" class="output-value">7777777</p>
  </div>
</div>
```